# what is the difference between /\ and ~ in package.json file for ex. "lodash": "^2.4.1" and "protractor": "~2.2.0"

Tags: npm, package.json

I am not sure where to use /\ symbol or ~ symbol in dependencies section with any module version.

Please clarify it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json):

```
~version "Approximately equivalent to version" See semver(7)
^version "Compatible with version" See semver(7)
```

So, not too helpful, right? The [semantic versioning calculator](http://semver.npmjs.com/) has a much more helpful description:

> `~` will include everything greater than a particular version in the
>   same minor range
>
> `^` will include everything greater than a particular version in the
>   same major range

So…

- `^2.4.1` would install 2.4.2 and 2.5.0
- `~2.4.1` would install 2.4.2 but not 2.5.0